# pgRouting: Nodes vs. Source/Target

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, network, nodes

I am working within a local city government on creating a routing network and started last week with little to no knowledge of pgRouting. I want the routing network to be used by our fire department and public schools. A series of travel-time buffers radiating from each fire-station is my goal. Example: how far can we travel in 1 min? 5min? 10min? from each station.

I found what visual I am looking for via:https://anitagraser.com/2011/02/12/drive-time-isochrones/

So far I have successfully created a database for the routing, created both extensions (PostGIS & pgRouting), imported my shapefile road centerlines successfully into my database, and lastly I ran pgr_createtopology. The results are great! My pgRouting plugin within QGIS works flawlessly. The next step is where I need help!

Should I create nodes? Or, alternatively, can I just use the vertices from the ""_vertices_pgr table generated from function: pgr_createTopology?

The ""_vertices_pgr table contains an "id" column but I can't see any column with any geographic data within the table. Is this why we can't use the vertices table? Is there something I am misunderstanding about creating a node network when I already have vertices created from pgr_createTopology?

Comment: The vertices table does have a point geometry column (`the_geom`). The `id` column is referenced by the `target` or `source` column in the original segments table.   If you *don't* have a geometry column in the vertices table, something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 4):

For shortest path Dijkstra or driving distance queries you only need a valid network topology with `source` and `target` attributes in the network table.

The `_vertices_pgr` table is generated when you run `pgr_createTopology` function or when you use `osm2pgrouting`. It can be convenient later, for example when you want to link the node geometries with the result of your drivetime query. `

In case you want to recreate the vertices table, you can use [`pgr_createVerticesTable`](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_createVerticesTable.html#pgr-create-vert-table) function.

The `id` column in the vertices table can be linked with the `source` and `tatget` coulmn of the network table.